# Как ограничить количество символов в Text Field в Objective-C (xCode)

Tags: xcode, ios, objective-c, iphone

Гуглил, искал, ничего так и не нашел, в параметрах text field нету. Получается, условием?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Плохо гуглил.

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
   NSUInteger newLength = [textField.text length] + [string length] - range.length;
   return (newLength > 25) ? NO : YES;
}
```

Можно еще про UIFont почитать, там тоже есть полезные методы для вычисления размера шрифта, сколько он занимает по высоте и длине в текстовом поле. Очень удобная штуковина.

Comment: В KomuOtpravit1  передается UITextField которое делегирует событие. Попробуй проставить tag для каждого текстового поля, а в этой функции просто проверяй по тегам. можешь switch case заюзать.

Comment: Тут кода не надо..
Если текстфилды делал в интерфейс билдере, то выдели текстовое поле и найди в проперти пармаетр "Tag" или по русски "тег" вроди бы. раставь всем текстовым полям уникальные теги.
А в методе добавь проверку на тег:
     
     if([KomuOtpravit1 tag] ==0 ) блаблабла

тегами ты подписываешь уникальность текстовых полей. Таким образом ты их можешь идентифицировать.

Comment: Да возможно ты мне пригодишься ) но я во вк не сижу, есть но не сижу, а в скайпе я bimawa..